# How to create a model with data that is not required in the mongo schema

Tags: class, model

I need to create a model class, that have all the properties in the signup form.
but there is some properties that are not required!
how I can make this class and set those properties as not required?

```
export class CompanyModel {
  companyName: string;
  companyEmail: string;
  password: string;
  logo: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  country: string;
  city: string;
  degree: string;
  relatedJobs: // this is not required property//
}
```

Comment: Change `relatedJobs:` to `relatedJobs?:`. The `?` makes the property optional.

Comment: @R.Richards 
Thank you so much.